# Can't understand connection between results and Function

Tags: haskell

I really can't understand the connection between the Function and the results it creates. I have the following Haskell code

```
data Expr = Num Integer | Add Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr

genExpr' :: Gen Expr
genExpr' = frequency
    [ (1,  do n <- arbitrary
              return (Num n)
      )
    , (1,  do a <- genExpr (1 `div` 2)
              b <- genExpr (1 `div` 2)
              return (Add a b)
      )
    , (1,  do a <- genExpr (1 `div` 2)
              b <- genExpr (1 `div` 2)
              return (Mul a b)
      )
    ]
```

It generates the following results in the console when i run "sample genExpr'"

```
0*0
-2
-1
1*-3
-1+-6
-7*1
9*10
10+3
-8+15
2*-3
-13
```

And what makes the results to be 11 in total??

Comment: Where is `Gen` imported from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[For context, I'm assuming you mean `Gen` as defined in the `QuickCheck` library.]

The output you're seeing has as much to do with `sample` than with the generator you have written.

The definition of `sample` is:

```
-- | Generates some example values and prints them to 'stdout'.
sample :: Show a => Gen a -> IO ()
sample g =
  do cases <- sample' g
     mapM_ print cases

-- | Generates some example values.
sample' :: Gen a -> IO [a]
sample' g =
  generate (sequence [ resize n g | n <- [0,2..20] ])
```

So `sample` takes a generator, runs the helper function `sample'` on it, and then prints all the results of `sample'` on screen.

The function `sample` takes a generator, and uses `generate` to "call" it a number of times at different sizes (using `resize`). How many times is determined by the list comprehension. The list comprehension is using the input sizes `[0,2..20]`, which is a list expanding to 11 elements. This is why you're ultimately seeing 11 results.

So you're ultimately getting to see 11 random values, generated using your generator.

Comment: So that means its always going to be 11 elements generated? @kosmikus. And if i would like to pick any of the returned 11 elems, would be logical to call head $ sample genExpr'?

Comment: The function `sample` is just there for debugging purposes. Yes, it will always generate and print 11 elements. If you use the generator normally within QuickCheck, then QuickCheck will use it to generate as many elements as needed.